# Multi-threading for downloading NCBI files in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib2

So recently I have taken on the task of downloading large collection of files from the ncbi database. However I have run into times where I have to create multiple databases. This code here which works to downloads all the viruses from the ncbi website. My question is there any way to speed up the process of downloading these files.

Currently the runtime of this program is more than 5hours. I have looked into multi-threading and could never get it to work because some of these files take more than 10seconds to download and I do not know how to handle stalling. (new to programing) Also is there a way of handling urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway. I get this sometimes with with certain combinations of retstart and retmax. This crashes the program and I have to restart the download from a different location by changingthe 0 in the for statement.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#This is the SearchQuery into NCBI. Spaces are replaced with +'s.
SearchQuery = 'viruses[orgn]+NOT+Retroviridae[orgn]'
#This is the Database that you are searching.
database = 'protein'
#This is the output file for the data
output = 'sample.fasta'


#This is the base url for NCBI eutils.
base = 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/'
#Create the search string from the information above
esearch = 'esearch.fcgi?db='+database+'&term='+SearchQuery+'&usehistory=y'
#Create your esearch url
url = base + esearch
#Fetch your esearch using urllib2
print url
content = urllib2.urlopen(url)
#Open url in BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup(content)
#Grab the amount of hits in the search
Count = int(doc.find('count').string)
#Grab the WebEnv or the history of this search from usehistory.
WebEnv = doc.find('webenv').string
#Grab the QueryKey
QueryKey = doc.find('querykey').string
#Set the max amount of files to fetch at a time. Default is 500 files.
retmax = 10000
#Create the fetch string
efetch = 'efetch.fcgi?db='+database+'&WebEnv='+WebEnv+'&query_key='+QueryKey
#Select the output format and file format of the files. 
#For table visit: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/table/chapter4.chapter4_table1
format = 'fasta'
type = 'text'
#Create the options string for efetch
options = '&rettype='+format+'&retmode='+type


#For statement 0 to Count counting by retmax. Use xrange over range
for i in xrange(0,Count,retmax):
    #Create the position string
    poision = '&retstart='+str(i)+'&retmax='+str(retmax)
    #Create the efetch URL
    url = base + efetch + poision + options
    print url
    #Grab the results
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    #Write output to file
    with open(output, 'a') as file:
        for line in response.readlines():
            file.write(line)
    #Gives a sense of where you are
    print Count - i - retmax
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To download files using multiple threads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shutil
from contextlib import closing
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads
from urllib2 import urlopen

def generate_urls(some, params): #XXX pass whatever parameters you need
    for restart in range(*params):
        # ... generate url, filename
        yield url, filename

def download((url, filename)):
    try:
        with closing(urlopen(url)) as response, open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response, file)
    except Exception as e:
        return (url, filename), repr(e)
    else: # success
        return (url, filename), None

def main():
    pool = Pool(20) # at most 20 concurrent downloads
    urls = generate_urls(some, params)
    for (url, filename), error in pool.imap_unordered(download, urls):
        if error is not None:
           print("Can't download {url} to {filename}, "
                 "reason: {error}".format(**locals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: @DarthBunny: `HTTPError` has `code` attribute e.g., 404 (not found), 400 (bad request). If you think some error are temporary then collect these urls in `if error is not None` block and repeat the loop (a limited number of times). I've used `repr(e)` as a function that is least likely to break. You could return just `e` if you use threads, not processes and access `e.code` in `if error is not None` block

Comment: @DarthBunny: to check that the download is correct, you could inspect `response` headers e.g., `Content-Length` to find out  the size in bytes and to compare it with the downloaded file. Partial download might be due to exceptions during the copying, you could delete `os.remove(filename)` in `except Exception` block. If all results are from the same site then read its TOS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use multithreading, it's the right way for downloading tasks.

```
"these files take more than 10seconds to download and I do not know how to handle stalling",
```

I don't think this would be a problem because Python's multithreading will handle this, or I'd rather say multithreading is just for this kind of I/O-bound work. When a thread is waiting for download to complete, CPU will let other threads do their work.

Anyway, you'd better at least try and see what happen.

Comment: A caveat to this advice is that, if the collection of files is truly large, and you try to have one thread for downloading each file, you could crash the python interpreter. I did something like this in OS X, and when my downloader reached around 120 threads the interpreter crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to effect your task. 1. Using process instead of thread, multiprocess is the module you should use. 2. Using Event-based, gevent is the right module.

502 error is not your script's fault. Simply, following pattern could be used to do retry

```
try_count = 3
while try_count > 0:
    try:
        download_task()
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        clean_environment_for_retry()
    try_count -= 1
```

In the line of except, you can refine the detail to do particular things according to concrete HTTP status code.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into incorporating more try, catch statements in my code. I was more looking for a way to do multi-threading